# Are passengers traveling together allowed to share the metromoney card in Tbilisi?

Tags: public-transport, georgia-country, tbilisi

In many cities you can share your metrocard (multiple persons validate the same card when getting on the metro or bus). Is this allowed for the [metromoney card](http://ttc.com.ge/?lang_id=ENG&sec_id=155) card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're not allowed to do this, given that the card always requires a minute between validations, and there are guards at the barriers to see to it that there is no abuse.

However, if you save the original receipt, [you can get the 2 lari back when leaving Tbilisi](http://ttc.com.ge/?lang_id=ENG&sec_id=155) (if less than 1 month after buying the card), by presenting your card, receipt and passport at a ticket counter

Comment: I don't think that is true, I am Georgian and from the day they introduced Metro Cards, you could use as many times as you want in a row. Now, I don't live in Georgia for 4 years anymore, but I was there in summer 2016 and it was still the same, remember very well I used for me and my friend, two validations in two seconds. Also, never heard any rule that says you are now allowed to do that.

Comment: @Leonardo I saw a foreign couple get shouted at at Marjanishvili station for trying to share a card, and they were forced to get another one. This was in November 2016. Also, once when I validated, I had to run back to fetch something quickly, and I couldn't enter the barrier for another 45 seconds

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that the card itself [costs a mere 2 lari](http://first2board.com/wanderlusty/2015/10/how-to-ride-the-tbilisi-metro/) - which is less than **$1** - I don't see why you would need to share one. Simply get two (or more) cards for each person and top them up individually. A single ride is around $0.20 so it won't break your budget.

Comment: The problem with multi persons is not the 2 Lari. When you are in a trip with several persons, it takes more time to Top Up each time several cards, and most chances you will stay with more unused balance.

Comment: These cards are fun. For example, in Moscow you flat out may share a card, in St. Petersburg flat out can't, and in Kharkov you can't use it on the same turnstile but may use on the adjacent. In all cases the price is (was?) flat so neither ends up in cheating.